# How to force mapped items into row instead of column?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm making a keyboard in a react app, generated by the following component:

**Keypad.js**

```
const Keypad = () => {

    const letters = [
        'Q',
        'W',
        'E',
        'R',
        'T',
        'Y',
        'U',
        'I',
        'O',
// etc
    ]

    return(
        <div>
            {letters.map((letter,index) => {
                return(
                    <div className="keyboard-container" key = {index}>
                        <div className="key">{letter}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
 
export default Keypad;
```

I want the letters rendered in rows, but they're being rendered instead in one column. Either that, or each letter is being assigned it's own row. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here's the CSS:

```
.keyboard-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.keyboard-container .key {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#69696d;
}
```

I've tried using inline styling in **Keypad.js**, as well as using a grid to try to organise the items.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out - I had put the `keyboard-conatiner` classname in the wrong place:

```
    return(
        <div className="keyboard-container">
            {letters.map((letter,index) => {
                return(
                    <div>
                        <div className="key">{letter}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```